# How to prevent accessing local sites from inside of a web server?

Tags: web-services, security

I'm writing a web service which is a sort of HTTP proxy: it takes an arbitrary URL from the user, loads some data from that URL and shows it to the user. Also I have some web services in my local network which I don't want to be viewed outside. The issue is that the user may input something like http://my-service.com?url=http://127.0.0.1:9292 and access the local services. How can I prevent that (in the most general and portable way)?

Comment: I thing the question is too broad when we know about your environment

Comment: I am going to share source code of the service, so it should prevent the user from accessing local services in any environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the service in a DMZ so you can control what it is able to access at all: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)

Also resolve the domain names to IPs - and blacklist all internal subnets in addition to the physical separation